# Show random images without repeat in Javascript

Tags: javascript, random

I'm a complete beginner in JavaScript with some experience in html and css. Anyway I'm trying to get a two random images everytime a user clicks on one of the two images. I've successfully implemented the code. However the images keep on repeating. I spent a whole hour searching for a way to do that and I've found but it didn't work for me. This is my code and thanks in advance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My awesome website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script>
        function getRandomImage() {
            var images = new Array("1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg");
            var randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            var randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            if (randomNum1 == randomNum2) {
                var randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            }
            document.getElementById("firstPic").src = images[randomNum1]
            document.getElementById("secondPic").src = images[randomNum2]
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        My awesome website
    </div>
    <pre><h1><center><img src="1.jpg" width="300px" height="300px" id="firstPic" onclick="getRandomImage()" />   or  <img src="2.jpg" width="300px" height="300px" id="secondPic" onclick="getRandomImage()" /></center></h1></pre>
</body>
```

Edit: I've tried using this method but idk I'm wrong

```
<script>
        var images = new Array("1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg");
        var usedImgs = new Array();
            function getRandomImage() {
            var randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            var randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            while (randomNum1 == randomNum2) {
                randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            }
            if (!usedImgs) {
                document.getElementById("firstPic").src = images[randomNum1]
                document.getElementById("secondPic").src = images[randomNum2]
                usedImgs.push(randomNum1);
                usedImgs.push(randomNum2);
            }
            
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "they keep on repeating"? You mean you don't want to get the same image twice in a row?

Comment: What should happen when all the images are finished?

Comment: I mean I don't want the image to be shown more than once

Comment: My question is about how to prevent images from repeating not ideas about what will happen when they finsih

Comment: well that question was to understand do you need to loop your set of images when all of them will be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create sort of randomiser and re-grouper

```js
// Group your set of images randomly
const groupRandom = ([...arr]) => {
  // Suffle array method
  const shuffle = (a) => {
    for(let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
  }
  
  // Re-group
  const regroup = ([...arr]) => {
    let newArr = [], temp = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      temp.push(arr[i]);
      if(temp.length === 2) newArr.push(temp), temp = [];
    }
    return newArr;
  }
  
  // Do suffle and regroup
  arr = shuffle(arr);
  arr = regroup(arr);
  return arr;
}

// test
const images = groupRandom(["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg"]);

// Log
console.log(images);
```

Then you can implement it in your example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My awesome website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script>
    var groupRandom = function(arr) {
      // Suffle array method
      var shuffle = function(arr) {
        for(var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
        }
        return arr;
      }
  
      // Re-group
      var regroup = function(arr) {
        var newArr = [], temp = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          temp.push(arr[i]);
          if(temp.length === 2) newArr.push(temp), temp = [];
        }
        return newArr;
      }
  
      // Do suffle and regroup
      var arrSuffeled = shuffle(arr);
      var arrRegrouped = regroup(arrSuffeled);
      return arrRegrouped;
    };
    
    var randomImageArray = groupRandom([
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSCm-ZRY7tQpxNyZAY1DoUyqcPDjLxdijN2OA&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSz1cnemcZpezXe7VeDdnsuwNsdjj-wsqW3mA&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSBZxg_1SjUlIOxOt0kjK3VbzzNeV_t1pXM6g&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT8i7Jw88bGLRDxgYVrcgG7H8J3bHS7eaoYgA&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRQG43SPw7__lb5kq97jIigDqeEU5RFzZPbcg&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRi6VT0-3esZzzidJwNk-xFuWr7NDKn0JxBKQ&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSTavBZRe2R1EJcb29qjwhHBcuVz4k0KECebA&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSiQT3AF0XNgNDxk6lOS40O9NVAaMMu_Rf7Mw&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRhxxIS6QDXeSNZIS5ZicwMrENASa6kYJ0DgQ&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQuxP2c3L7G6YnNzHwmn7K8W4UWUkcnh9RNMw&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRBJ3DXGZI-62WJ9I2AEDM_EJKC9yRGDMhJJQ&usqp=CAU",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQ6HwnfnreAmYein1ZyMq0_G1rXGiaCBKvhdQ&usqp=CAU"
    ]);
    
    function getRandomImage() {
        // Check if image array not yet 0
        if(randomImageArray.length === 0) {
          alert('Array with images exhausted!');
          return false;
        }
        // Pop new group of images from array
        var newGroup = randomImageArray.pop();
        // Paste new images to img tags
        document.getElementById("firstPic").src = newGroup[0];
        document.getElementById("secondPic").src = newGroup[1];
    }
    
    // Run JS code when page (DOM) has been loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            getRandomImage();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        My awesome website
    </div>
    <pre><h1><center>
    <img src="" width="100px" height="100px" id="firstPic" onclick="getRandomImage()" />   or  <img src="" width="100px" height="100px" id="secondPic" onclick="getRandomImage()" />
    </center></h1></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Man, I said I'm an extreme beginner. Any easy way if you may

Comment: Updated my answer with implementation in your example

Comment: Well idk why it's not working on your side... Everything working - try to press "Run code snippet" under my second answer, there you can see and test the working example... I've added some demo online pics

Comment: Just one more question if you may. I want to remove the place holder I mean the image src but still get random image once I opened the page and One more thing when I'm at the last two pics I can't click on any of them, If you can edit your code so once all the pics are finished I get an alert or anything in such a way that I can click on the last two pics

Comment: "My question is about how to prevent images from repeating not ideas about what will happen when they finsih" (C) NabilTheCoder... ;) Anyway I've updated answer, check it out

Comment: AHAHAHAHA thank you but still I want two random images at the start of the website ;)

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that part. You need to run some JS function automatically when the page loads. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Issue A**

You mean that it's still possible to get 2 of the same images at a time? That is because you only retry once.

Change this:

```
if (randomNum1 == randomNum2) {
    var randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
}
```

To a while numbers are the same, keep on trying to get a new random number:

```
while(randomNum1 == randomNum2) {
    randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
}
```

**Issue B**

```
var images = new Array("1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg");
var imagesToShow = [].concat(images); // Duplcate array so we don't update the original array.
function getRandomImage() {
        
        var randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesToShow.length);
        var randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesToShow.length);
        while(randomNum1 == randomNum2) {
            randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesToShow.length);
        }
        document.getElementById("firstPic").src = imagesToShow[randomNum1];
        document.getElementById("secondPic").src = imagesToShow[randomNum2];

        // Now remove the 2 items from the array
        //  the way below doesn't use splice becuase you have 2 indexes and that will cause issues aswell
        imagesToShow[randomNum1] = null;
        imagesToShow[randomNum2] = null;
        imagesToShow = imagesToShow.filter((it) => !!it); // Filter out the null values.

       // refill the array when we are out of images.
       if(imagesToShow.length < 2){
           imagesToShow = [].concat(images);
       }
    }
```

Comment: That's one issue yeah, but you can read the issue they're wanting to solve in the comments.

Comment: No, that is working more than perfect but my question is to never repeat the same image twice

Comment: I have added a new update. Show only images once. But reset the array when there are no more images left.

Answer (score 0):

Just change one line on your code and make the function as arrow function like below. Please check below code. I hope it will be helpfull.

```
        <script>
            let getRandomImage = () => {
              var images = new Array(
                "1.jpg",
                "2.jpg",
                "3.jpg",
                "4.jpg",
                "5.jpg",
                "6.jpg",
                "7.jpg",
                "8.jpg",
                "9.jpg",
                "10.jpg",
                "11.jpg",
                "12.jpg"
            );

            var randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
            var randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

            if (randomNum1 == randomNum2) {
                return getRandomImage();
            }
            document.getElementById("firstPic").src = images[randomNum1];
            document.getElementById("secondPic").src = images[randomNum2];
        };
    </script>
```